Why does the local environment variable of view have no effect on date in SwiftUI
I achieve the function of change languages within the app by modifying the locale environment variable of each view, and it worked well, except for date formatting.
final class AppState: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var language: String = "en"
    
    init() {
        var id = Locale.current.identifier;
        if let userLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "language") {
            id = userLanguage
        }
        
        if id.hasPrefix("zh") {
            _language = Published(initialValue: "zh-Hans")
        }
    }
}

// Action change language
private func select(for language: String) {
    appState.language = language
    UserDefaults.standard.set(language, forKey: "language")
}

// I added a modifier to each view
.environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: appState.language))

I have a text view for displaying dates, but it cannot display the correct format according to the current view locale environment. I don't known why.
Text(date.formatted(Date.FormatStyle().month(.abbreviated).day(.defaultDigits).weekday(.abbreviated)))

I customized a date formatter in another view, and it works, but there's no date style I want
private var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: appState.language)
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    return formatter
}

// This works ok, but it is not what I want, I just want a date style like 'Wen, Apr 13th'
Text(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))

Thanks.

date.formatted( isn't using the environment use Text with format

You did not pass a locale to formatted. formatted is not going to magically know what SwiftUI environment it is in.
You can give the FormatStyle to a Text, which does know what environment it is in, and let Text do the formatting:
Text(date, format:
    Date.FormatStyle().month(.abbreviated).day(.defaultDigits).weekday(.abbreviated)
)

In general, you can get the locale with @Environment, and pass it to the format style:
@Environment(\.locale) var locale

// ...

date.formatted(
    Date.FormatStyle(locale: locale).month(.abbreviated).day(.defaultDigits).weekday(.abbreviated)
)


The statement formatted is not going to magically know what SwiftUI environment it is in is not right. The way SwiftUI resolves Locale is quite weird
If we use  String(localized: "Refresh") , though we don't pass Environment Locale it will automatically somehow uses it to translate. But the same will not work with Date.formatted. Which APIs use Environment Locale is not known.

@RaviRaj what I mean is that SwiftUI has its own “environment”, independent from other non-SwiftUI APIs. String(localized: "Refresh") translates the string, not using whatever is in SwiftUI’s environment, but Locale.current.

No, String(localized: "Refresh") is normal Swift API but it translates using SwiftUI environment Locale. You can test it.

@RaviRaj Well this exact question shows that it is not the case. Can you reproduce the issue stated in the question?
